# openn Cv2 drawing Contours

Tags: python, opencv

i m running this code but i m getting an error

```
cv2.drawContours(image,contours,-1,(0,255,0),3)

error: OpenCV(3.4.3) D:\Build\OpenCV\opencv-3.4.3\modules\imgproc\src\drawing.cpp:2511: error: (-215:Assertion failed) npoints > 0 in function 'cv::drawContours'
```

---

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image=cv2.imread("C:/Users/AnushkaGupta/Desktop/image database/input1.jpg")
cv2.imshow("original image",image)
cv2.waitKey(0)

gray=cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

edged=cv2.Canny(gray,30,200)
cv2.imshow("Canny Edges",edged)
cv2.waitKey(0)

contours,hierarchy, _=cv2.findContours(edged,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cv2.imshow("canny Edges After Contouring",edged)
cv2.waitKey(0)

print("Number of Contours found ="+str(len(contours)))



cv2.drawContours(image,contours,-1,(0,255,0),3)

cv2.imshow("Contours",image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you collect the output of findContours(), the order should be as follows:

```
image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(...)
```

In your specific case you should write (I omitted the imshow steps):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread("./input1.jpg")

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 30, 200)

_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edged, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

print(f"Number of Contours found = {len(contours)}")

cv2.drawContours(image, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
```